# Factory pattern can be used to create business objects?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have read various articles on the factory pattern. However almost in all the examples the objects used are "flat" (beans, dtos,) ie. Dogs, Cars, etc. and that's good it helped me understand. But what about service objects, those that execute specific logic.

For example, let's say I want to create an app that supports **credit card** and **debit card** payments. Assuming that the logic is different for both cases, my idea is to create an interface *`CardPayment`* with both implementations: *`CreditCardPayemnt`* and *`DebitCardPayemnt`*.

The following would be to create the **factory class** that will return an object of type `CardPayment` (instantiated with one of the implementations based on some input parameter)

In this way, the `processPayment()` (method from `CardPayment` interface)could be executed without caring about the type of payment.

[image]

**Would this be a valid use of the factory pattern?** My concern is based on the fact that factory is a creational pattern and what I propose here is yes the creation of an object (`CardPayment`), but it is more behavior oriented.

Most of the examples I've seen consist of objects that have different attributes so it's useful to use factory to create one or the other, but what about objects that are different because their operation itself is different.

Comment: From my 12-years-experience point of view it's absolutely ok. If you see factory class is handy in your particular case - use it. Both classes are of the same interface, hiding the implementation is the purpose of interface, returning different implementations according to some logic is typical for a factory pattern.